# ACL for openstack dashboard security

Tags: security, openstack, acl, cloud-security, private-cloud

I am trying to find a way to secure openstack dashboard from Dos attack using ACL, if there is a way, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACLs are for controlling access to files in a file system, not network access.  So, basically, ACLs will not help you here.

What you need is a firewall or packet filter in front of your Horizon instance.